# Scrapy KeyError: 'Spider not found', yet spider exists when executing 'scrapy list' in terminal

Tags: python, scrapy

I am attempting to scrape the text within the CSS title tag from a demo website. When attempting to run the spider named 'quotes' A KeyError: 'Spider not found' is thrown. When running 'scrapy list' in the terminal, it returns 'quotes', the name of my spider. SPIDER_MODULES and NEWSPIDER_MODULE are not empty.
. The file tree is:

/Users/paulsutton/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Projects/Web\ Scrapy\ Playground/virtual_env/scrapy_test/scrapy_test

```
class testSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'qoutes'
    start_urls = [
        "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title::text').extract()
        yield {'titletext': title}
```

Comment: You misstyped the spider's name, "qoutes" instead of "quotes"

Comment: Tried so many things and low and behold you are right, a stupid spelling error. Thank you lol.